# how to add webapi to aspx web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a website that display the page -Default.aspx, Now I added a webapi controler class to the project., how can I get it running., ie, if I just create a Post request with my URL it is not working.  below is my webapi controller class, how can I integrate this to my current website- so I can do  post requests and get the return string.

```
public class Valcontrol : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public String Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
       return "Test";              
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

If I do a Post request to "www.xyz.in" am getting the whole webpage in my return stream instead of the string "Test" that I am returning in my Post function above.

Client call in my App - Java code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.xyz.in/");
            // get the payuConfig first
            String postParam = "Dev";  
            byte[] postParamsByte = postParam.getBytes("UTF-8");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postParamsByte.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postParamsByte);
            InputStream responseInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer responseStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] byteContainer = new byte[1024];
            for (int i; (i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer)) != -1; ) {
                responseStringBuffer.append(new String(byteContainer, 0, i));
            }
            String strResponse = responseStringBuffer.toString();
```

Below is the content that got added to my web.config(by visual studio) file when I added webapi class to my project.

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: Your string comes back in the data of the ajax request... Make sure you're including the value in the post you're making or it may not map propertly

Comment: one fundamental doubt,  to confirm if am doing things right., in the client app am sending Post request to my default URL of my website, should  I use /api/Valcontrol to execute the Post event?

Comment: Yeah you were probably making the post request correctly, you just didn't have your controller named appropiately

Comment: Show the client call with the body message

Comment: @MarcusH updated the question above..

Answer (score 0):

This swill not work Valcontrol is not a valid name for a controller.  Controllers need to have the Suffix Controller in order for them to map correctly.

So you need to change the name to ValController, or ValControlController.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public String Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
       return "Test";              
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

then make your post request like so:

```
POST  api/val?value=Test
```

and change your headers to Content-Type:application/json

Comment: Change your content type as well try using the class i've provided above

Comment: 1) in my client app i have to change  - conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/application/json");  - done., 2) Update class name -done., 3) I noticed you have added  [Route("api/[controller]")] - If i add this, Visual studio shows error."The type or namespace Route could not be found."   4) Dint understand the statement "POST  api/val?value=Test"    - kindly explain..

Comment: @user1066231 That is the route syntax works with the latest versions of .NET I'm not sure what you are running but that should set up the the post route to your controller minus Controller prefix I.E ValuesController would turn to Values.

Comment: @user1066231 the Last statement is what your post request should look like, you post request takes in a value `Value` make sure its assigned when sending the post request